# How to add two images in Pushbutton using CSS QT?

Tags: css, qt

I am in need of adding two images to the pushbutton!!! The first image must be default and the second image when clicked it should be active..
I have tried this code but its not working properly!!!

```
QPushButton{background-image: url(:/images/activity.png);}     
QPushButton:pressed{background-image: url(:/images/activity_active.png);}
```

Anyone please help me in sorting this mistake made by me?

Comment: Not sure that CSS has any "pressed" selector. Can you set up a jsfiddle so we can see and fix the problem?

Comment: I dont know about jsfiddle option Walkerneo... i too taught that pressed wont suit.. i saw this url:http://wiki.maemo.org/Customising_Qt_look_and_feel_and_Python_in_30_Mins#Add_Colours_and_Images.. Juz check this out

Comment: In qt i think i dont have any option ,. its an online editor right ,. ,i wont be suitable.. We use UI design along with CSS

Answer (score 0):

The [Style Sheet example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/widgets-stylesheet.html) that comes with Qt has everything you need to see how this is done. Look in your Qt SDK folder for something like `QtSDK\Examples\4.7\widgets\stylesheet`.

**Update:**

When you run that example program, you can use the `File` menu and select `Edit Style...` to edit the active style sheet. Choose the `Pagefold` style. Back at the main screen you will notice that the `OK` and `Cancel` buttons are using multiple images for the up, down and hover states.

These states map to the images in `QtSDK\Examples\4.7\widgets\stylesheet\images` directory: `pushbutton.png`, `pushbutton_pressed.png`, and `pushbutton_hover.png` respectively.

The style sheet for mapping these images to the buttons is `QtSDK\Examples\4.7\widgets\stylesheet\pagefold.qss`. It's possible that Qt's unfortunate convention of using `.qss` as a file extension for stylesheets is confusing you.

In here you will find the following relevant selectors:

```
QPushButton, QComboBox[editable="false"],
QComboBox[editable="true"]::drop-down {
    border-image: url(:/images/pushbutton.png) 5;
    border-width: 5;
}

QPushButton:hover, QComboBox[editable="false"]:hover,
QComboBox[editable="true"]::drop-down:hover, QMenuBar::item:hover {
    border-image: url(:/images/pushbutton_hover.png) 5;
    border-width: 5;
}

QPushButton:pressed, QComboBox[editable="false"]:on,
QComboBox[editable="true"]::drop-down:on, QMenuBar::item:on {
    border-image: url(:/images/pushbutton_pressed.png) 5;
    border-width: 5;
}
```

The button images are referenced using the path prefix `:/` which corresponds to images stored in a Qt resource file. It is not necessary for the images to be compiled into a resource. They could also be identified by absolute or relative file paths.

To have these style sheets take effect, they need to be loaded into a `QString` and assigned to the application object or some widget in the parent hierarchy of your target buttons. In the example program, the code that does this is in the `loadStyleSheet()` method:

```
void StyleSheetEditor::loadStyleSheet(const QString &sheetName)
{
    QFile file(":/qss/" + sheetName.toLower() + ".qss");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString styleSheet = QLatin1String(file.readAll());

    ui.styleTextEdit->setPlainText(styleSheet);
    qApp->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
    ui.applyButton->setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: There Is no solution for it!! only the example is given in it.. I need to add two images and display first one as default and when the button is pressed it should change the image ???

Comment: I dont want to know about stylesheet.the fact is i am in need of the images. there is no solution in this QtSDK\Examples\4.7\widgets\stylesheet.

Comment: The example contains exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: But i could not find the pushbutton that contains two images,first one to be default and other should blink when clicked.,., help me in finding this please

Comment: Hi arnold spence.. u had given me a answer which is almost correct.. the only thing is when i press or click the button the second image should be displayed.. you had given is blinking.,. which is what i too asked first.. but i am sorry for that.. I am in need to have the second image at top of first image.. ie,when clicked the button image1 should change to image2.. pls help me out!!!

Comment: I'm not sure that I am understanding you correctly. If you are talking about a toggle button then you should be able to call `setCheckable(true)` on the button to make it act as a toggle. In your style sheet you can remove the selectors for `:hover` and `:pressed` and use `QPushButton:checked` instead. This will cause the button to switch between the normal and checked images.

Comment: i will check this :checked and let you know.. Arnold

Comment: I had checked this :checked option but not working.. I will explain you from first.. In a push-button i need to add two background images.. the first image should be always active.. when we click the button again the second image should come and must be in active until the next button is pressed....did u get my point now????

Comment: like that i have 4 buttons where i will be setting for all the buttons a default image.,. when the second button is clicked, it should change the image,. similarly for others too

Comment: I'm afraid I am still having trouble understanding what you mean. Perhaps you could include in your question some images that demonstrate the effect you are looking for or maybe link to a video that shows something similar.

Comment: Let me explain you again in a much simpler way as possible.else i will send you the complete details... Consider 4 pushbuttons with background image in them and they are default.ok., Then,when pressing or clicking the second button there should be a change in image,such that second button is active...like that when i press the third button,the default image must be disabled and another image should be in active..,. did u get my point now... this is the simple link in which i got an basic idea ......http://wiki.maemo.org/Customising_Qt_look_and_feel_and_Python_in_30_Mins#Add_Colours_and_Images

Comment: Are you describing radio buttons then where you have a group of buttons and only one of them can be "selected" at a time? If that's the case, then in addition to calling `setCheckable(true)` on each button, call `setAutoExclusive(true)` for each button as well. This will make them act like radio buttons.